# While using present continuous tense should I end it with time point?

Tags: present-continuous

While using present continuous tense should I end it with time point (based on the grammar rules)?

For example:

- He is studying.

or

- He is studying **now**

?

I was told in the past the when having present continuous tense I should add time point such as: now, right now, at the moment, or at present etc. But practically speaking I don't see that people follow such rule. What is the explanation for that? There are three possible choices: 1) I was told wrong thing 2) people wrong, 3) I didn't understand what I was told.

Comment: You were misled. You could specify the time if this were important but it's not necessary. E.g **Everybody is looking for John who should already be here.** *He is waiting in the hall now, as we speak*

Answer (score 1):

Here is what *MyGrammarLab elementary* by M.Foley and D.Hall says about the use of time expressions in question:

[image]

You see, we **often** use such words and phrases, not always - only when it's necessary.